# How to restrict ExposedDropdownMenu to enter text in AutocompleteTextViw

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design

I am using ExposedDropdownMenu in the application where I don't want to enter a text in it.It should only choose items from the dropdownlist.It works fine in the normal case but if I tap on other 
EditText and quickly tap on ExposedDropdownMenu and type text,the text get reflected in the ExposedDropdownMenu.How to fix this issue

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow without seeing it, but perhaps this is a bug that should be reported to the library's bug tracker?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding TouchListener and showDropDown() in it.

```
 binding.etType.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

           binding.etType.showDropDown();
            return false;
       }
    });
```